# Split a variable length qouted string

Tags: unix, awk, gawk

I have a variable length string which looks like the following:

```
-DFOO -DBAR="1 2 3" -DTEST="\"asdf asdf\""
```

Which I would like to split into several lines, using space as delimiter (except if they occur in quotes).

The expected result of the example is:

```
-DFOO
-DBAR="1 2 3"
-DTEST="\"asdf asdf\""
```

How can I do this using "normal" unix tool. I tried with AWK but without any luck, most references of solving this problem with AWK had a fixed number of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want `"normal" unix tool.`:

**awk**:

```
awk -F' -' -v OFS='\n-' '$1=$1'
```

test

```
kent$  echo '-DFOO -DBAR="1 2 3" -DTEST="\"asdf asdf\""'|awk -F' -' -v OFS='\n-' '$1=$1'
-DFOO
-DBAR="1 2 3"
-DTEST="\"asdf asdf\""
```

**sed**

```
kent$  sed 's/ -/\n-/g' <<< '-DFOO -DBAR="1 2 3" -DTEST="\"asdf asdf\""'                 
-DFOO                                                                   
-DBAR="1 2 3"
-DTEST="\"asdf asdf\""
```

or **grep**

```
kent$  echo '-DFOO -DBAR="1 2 3" -DTEST="\"asdf asdf\""'|grep -oP -e'-[^-]*' 
-DFOO 
-DBAR="1 2 3" 
-DTEST="\"asdf asdf\""
```

Comment: I regret that I have but one vote to give for that use of grep.